# Is it possible to access angular app data from an external Javascript Code in the same project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So, this is a theoretical question because I don't have to encounter this problem. But I'm just wondering.

Let say I have an Angular Project Compilated in My PROJECT FOLDER.

```
 <br/>  In this PROJECT FOLDER, I have the other JAVASCRIPT FILE, EXTERNAL to my Angular Project.
  <br/>
```

In this EXTERNAL Javascript Files, I Would like to access a data or a variable from a file in my Angular Project.

Could it be Possible?

Like an import/export from a file in my Angular Project to a Javascript file Outside of my Compilated Angular.

The part where I'm concerned about is the fact that Angular is compiled in production.

In development, I could easily write a path to an angular file. But Once it's compilated, what would happen?

So is it possible? If yes, how?  When using tools like Webpack?

Answer (score 1):

It's totally possible, **given certain conditions**.

In case you haven't played with it yet, know that you have a `ng` global variable in your Angular projects, that is bound to your window.

You can use it with something like this

```
ng.probe(document.querySelector('app-root')).componentInstance
```

And that should return your app component instance (assuming you use the correct selector).

But this can be done **only if the code isn't minified**, and maybe even *when you serve your application* (not checked this one).

Other than that, I am not aware of any other technique to access angular features through another script.

Comment: I suppose It's also possible to store it in the Storage (Local or Session), 
But You don't want to do this for any type of data and it seems more a "I don't have any better choice" option than anything.

Comment: No it's not possible to store it in the storage, since the storage is for primitive types. But you could store it in the window, except that since it's minified, it wouldn't be of great help.